# Is it safe to publish keys from App Engine's NDB?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a RESTfull service to store and retrieve JSON. Payloads are stored in NDB, so in order to access an entity the user has to provide the key. Is it safe and secure to return ndb.Model.key().urlsafe() upon entity creation or should I develop my own unique ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, this depends. If you're returning this key to the user, they can find the entity name and identifier of that object. If you're also accepting these keys *from* the user in a future request, they could construct one to point to any object in your datastore, so you must do any required permission/type checking before loading an object for a key they pass to you.

There's also the issue that if you later decide you want to change, say, how you store those models, you are a bit stuck by the fact that you've exposed an implementation detail by sending down the NDB key to the user. Generating your own unique ID might be better if you're worried about your users holding on to those identifiers for a long time.

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation that talks about this: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#retrieving_entities